# WaitForSeconds is not being called

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I want to hide a button at start and have it become active again after a certain amount of time. However, the call to `WaitForSeconds()` isn't working.

I've tried the following:

- Having other methods call WaitForSeconds
- Accessing `bool` values from other scripts to skip over WaitForSeconds
- The StartCoroutine approach

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class HideUnhideBtn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button buttonToHide;
    public float comeInTime = 32.5f;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        buttonToHide.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(comeInTime);
        buttonToHide.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer up until now should not be valid. Start method can implemented as a coroutine as in the example in the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) and doesn't require StartCoroutine. Are you sure the gameobject with this monobehaviour use starts enable?

Comment: depending on creation order, are you sure buttontohide is available at this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Coroutines do not run on disabled objects

The answers up until now are incorrect because `Start()` can be used as a Coroutine directly and does not require `StartCoroutine` as from this [example in the Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) (alas Unity is not very explicit on this functionality of Start).

Most likely you placed the `HideUnhideBtn` script on the same `GameObject` you wanted to disable. So this line `buttonToHide.gameObject.SetActive(false);` disables the object with your script, and by consequence stops the coroutine.

To solve the issue you need to use 2 different `GameObject`s.

1. For the button
2. For the script running the coroutine

The second `GameObject` needs to stay enabled for the entire time. If you disable it, you will kill the coroutine.

Comment: I can confirm that `Start` can be a coroutine. I'm complaining for a long time already that it is mentioned on most other methods in the docs (e.g. [`Awake cannot be a co-routine.`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html), [`OnCollisionEnter can be a co-routine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)) but wasn't mentioned in [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) were it often would make sense even more

Comment: @derHugo Start with the return type of IEnumerator is just awesome, didnt know it works for OnCollisionEnter aswell but thats great to know thanks. Does that work for the other Collision and Trigger callbacks aswell? Is there some documentation page where that is listed?

Comment: @yes No unfortunately not really and that's exactly what bothers me a bit sometimes .. the docs are often quite incomplete because it are "edge use cases" but fully agree it would be great to know! Mostly you have to find out by either checking the according api docs for each message or try ;)

Comment: Thank you so so much! I spent almost three hours of pulling my hair out to figure out what was wrong. You were right, I had the script attached to the button and all I had to do was attach it to an empty game object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the `StartCoroutine` function with the given coroutine as paramter in order for this to work.
call it for example in the start method like this
`StartCoroutine(Start());`

Comment: he is right, coroutines try to execute code not synchronously like your ususal program flow would allow for. technically they are executed in the same thread still and just switch inbetween tasks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to call a Coroutine like this:

```
public class HideUnhideBtn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button buttonToHide;
    public float comeInTime = 32.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(HideAndShowButton());
    }

    IEnumerator HideAndShowButton()
    {
        buttonToHide.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(comeInTime);
        buttonToHide.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Here the offical documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Enjoy!